# Use "of" or "for" with Institute, Department, Office...?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

When should which be used and what's the difference?

Department **of** XYZ
or
Department **for** XYZ

Institute **of** ABC
or
Institute **for** ABC

Federal Office **of**...
or
Federal Office **for**...

Is there any sort of rule for this?

The "problem" is that it's an ongoing debate in the Department (non-English-speaking country) on how to properly translate it into English.

Comment: Largely _of_ makes more sense, but _for_ is often used (in the UK government). If you're naming a government website, go look it up on their webpage. If you're naming departments within your own organisation, I'd go with _of_.

Comment: Use the official name as published, since it varies. For instance, Canada currently has a Minister *of* Foreign Affairs, but it used to have a Secretary of State *for* Foreign Affairs doing the same job.

Comment: The UK has a Department for Transport; the US has a Department of Transportation. Since *of* and *for* are both used, and the original name is not English, choose whichever sounds best. Unless the original name has a preposition, in which case translate that.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are specifically asking this question to avoid a possible embarrassing translation.

example:

```
Institute for the Criminally Insane
```

Most likely means an institute which helps and/or houses the criminally insane

```
Institute of the Criminally Insane
```

Perhaps is an institute run by persons who are criminally insane and/or an institute which advances the status of the criminally insane.

The second example is admittedly humorous and is intended to exaggerate the difference in connotation. Your use of either 'of' or 'for' should surely be determined by the context of the actual name it is to be applied to. No doubt someone in your own department's debate has mentioned a similar example to the one I have given.

Comment: Yes. "For" sounds more like it's in favour of the thing. "Ministry for Unemployment" wants more unemployment? "Ministry of War" is more factual while "Ministry for War" sounds like it's advocating war. "Department of the Unemployed/Veterans/Retired People/etc" sounds like it might be staffed by those groups.

Answer (score 2):

Whether one uses "of" or "for" depends on the semantics. If the subject is part of a whole, it is 'of' its genus.  If the subject represents, acts for or advocates a part (the object) - it is 'for' its subset. So we may say the University of the West Indies is the Secretariat for Caribbean Conferences.